# sharedpreferences is not being cleared in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I'm storing data on sharedpreferences when user is logged in and setting it in a textview. I want to remove one specific data when user logged out. The problem is data is being stored but not removing. I have tried below code.

```
public class SessionManager {
SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
Context _context;
int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

private static final String PREF_NAME = "NaafcoPref";
private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";
public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
public static final String KEY_RESULT = "result";
public static final String SCAN_RESULT = "s_result";

public SessionManager(Context context) {
    this._context = context;
    pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
}

public void createLoginSession(String id) {
    editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);
    editor.putString(KEY_ID, id);
    editor.commit();
}

public void getResult(String result) {
    editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);
    editor.putString(KEY_RESULT, result);
    editor.commit();
}

public void getScanResult(String scanResult) {
    editor.putString(SCAN_RESULT, scanResult);
    editor.commit();
}

public void checkLogin() {
    if (!this.isLoggedIn()) {
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, PointActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        _context.startActivity(i);
    }
}


public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
    user.put(KEY_ID, pref.getString(KEY_ID, null));
    user.put(KEY_RESULT, pref.getString(KEY_RESULT, null));
    user.put(SCAN_RESULT, pref.getString(SCAN_RESULT, null));
    return user;
}


public void logoutUser() {

    editor.remove(SCAN_RESULT).clear().commit();
    //editor.clear();
    //editor.commit();
    Intent i = new Intent(_context, MainActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    _context.startActivity(i);
}

public boolean isLoggedIn() {
    return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
}
}
```

Comment: Did you try using apply(); instead of commit(); ? Not sure if helps, maybe worth a try.

Comment: Yes i have tried

Comment: pref.edit().clear().commit(); should clear the SF. Is your problem solved? One more piece of advise- Use Context.MODE_PRIVATE in place of PRIVATE_MODE.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

Answer (score 2):

To **remove** specific values: `SharedPreferences.Editor.remove()` followed by a **commit()**

To remove them all `SharedPreferences.Editor.clear()` followed by a `commit()`

If you don't care about the return value and you're using this from your application's main thread, consider using `apply()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 public void logoutUser() {


   SharedPreferences sp = Preferences.getInstance().pref;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.remove(SCAN_RESULT);

            editor.commit();

        Intent i = new Intent(_context, MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        _context.startActivity(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing this for logout:

```
   /**
     * Clear All user preferences
     * Use this when user logs out
     */
    public void clearPreferences() {
        isLoggedIn(); // this will set the login as false
        pref.edit().clear().apply();
        //also clear from default preferences
        SharedPreferences defaultPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        defaultPref.edit().clear().apply();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinitialize sharepreference editer to clear data

```
 public void logoutUser() {
    editor = pref.edit();
    editor.clear().commit();
    Intent i = new Intent(_context, MainActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    _context.startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("s_result", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
pref.edit().clear().commit();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.

Comment: @Dev-iL, context means i am attaching the activity class to the action & ediit().remove() means it will remove only particular values that have save & edit().clear() means it's clear all values that u have saved..

Comment: :) You don't need to explain this to _me_ - my comment is a general thing you should keep in mind when posting answers. You should [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43247326/edit) you answer and add this information.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create singleton class like `PreferenceManager`

```
private PreferenceManager(Context ctx) {
        prefs = ctx.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(ctx.getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = prefs.edit();
    }

    public static PreferenceManager getInstance(Context ctx) {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new PreferenceManager(ctx);
        }
        return sInstance;
    }
```

You can use below snippet

```
public void clearPreference() {

        editor.remove("your preference key that you want to clear");
        .
        .add all preference key that you want to clear
        .
        editor.commit();
    }
```